# Converting base64 string to X509 certifcate

Tags: powershell, base64, x509

I use PowerShell and thus far I have figured out how to take a X509 certificate flat file e.g. Cert.cer and concert it to a Base64 string for storage (e.g. in a database as a string etc.) and then convert it back again into a System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 object

See my code below so far:

```
$CertifcateFileFullPath = "C:\temp\cert.cer"
$Cert = new-object security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2 -ArgumentList $CertifcateFileFullPath

$Obj2 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Cert.RawData)

$Obj3 = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Obj2))
```

Now the thing is I want to write the object `$obj3` back to the file system as a flat file (e.g. Cert.cer) which is readable/usable as the original certificate.

If I use | out-file C:\Temp2\Cert.cer   etc... I get a file which is much bigger than the original file and not readable (e.g. does not open as a normal cert file). I assume the encoding is the issue when writing out the object to the file system (I believe cert files are ASN 1 encode binary files)

Comment: The code above did not come out too well let me try to paste in again  $CertifcateFileFullPath = "C:\temp\cert.cer"

$Cert = new-object security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2 -ArgumentList $CertifcateFileFullPath

$Obj2 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Cert.RawData)

$Obj3 = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Obj2))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that PewrShell is Unicode by default, while CryptoAPI decoder expects an ASCII encoding (where each character is encoded by using one byte). To achieve this, add `-Encoding ASCII` paramter to `Out-File` cmdlet.

BTW, there is no need to store certificate file in binary format. CryptoAPI supports certificate files in Base64 format. Since .NET relies on CryptoAPI, then there will not be comatibility problems.

Comment: Thanks very much yet again Vadims :)